# Скрыть код, выдающий iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Загружаю часть своей другой страницы на определённую страницу. Расстроился результатом, что Iframe полностью копирует и выводит код в блоке iframe на моей странице (код просматривается в исходном коде странице). Например, когда вставляешь фрейм ютуба, то он почему-то не выдаёт html код всей страницы YouTube.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы код страницы, которая используется в iframe, не выводился в исходный код страницы.
Возможно, для этой задачи нужно не использовать iframe, а что-то иное?

Comment: Дело в разных доменах?

Comment: во фрейме ютуба у вас небось таки видео прописано в ссылке, а не просто `src="http://youtube.com"` ?

Comment: загрузите нужную часть своей другой страницы помощью аякса или еще чего.

Comment: @teran Пример кода?

Comment: @Дмитрий, приведи пример кода, как ты вставляешь свой iframe и youtube, сейчас непонятно что ты имеешь ввиду под выводом в исходный код страницы. в devtools всегда можно посмотреть содержимое iframe, если в этом iframe что-то есть.

Answer (score 2):

iframe не вставляет код подключаемой страницы в родительскую. В этом можно убедиться посмотрев в браузере исходный код страницы.

Но он добавляет элементы подключаемой страницы в DOM дерево родителя. Что вполне логичное поведение. Браузер отображает только те элементы, которые находятся в DOM дереве страницы

Comment: Ну что вы докопались до формулировки. Хорошо, уточню, не код, а DOM. Вопрос всё равно остаётся. У меня в html ссылки на видео, мне не надо, чтобы она выводилась в исходном коде этой страницы

Comment: @Дмитрий я не "докопался" до формулировки, а пытаюсь расшифровать ваш вопрос. После вашего комментария вообще ничего не понятно. В исходном коде страницы присутствует ровно то, что сервер отдал в ответ на команду `GET`. Если у вас на странице присутствует какой-то элемент, то почему он должен пропасть из исходного кода страницы?

Comment: Зачем давать ответ, если он не о чем. Я поэтому и написал вопрос, чтобы узнать, как это сделать, а не слушать встречные вопросы

Comment: @Дмитрий при помощи этих "встречных вопросов" я пытаюсь понять, что же вы хотите узнать. Пока не получается

Comment: Удалите свой бессмысленный ответ

Comment: Дело пахнет скандалом? Вам человек пытается помочь разобраться, вы же считаете что вам все должны и должны делать как нравится вам. Но у вас во-первых, действительно не очень хорошо сформулированный вопрос (который как известно "половина ответа") и заметьте не один человек вам на это указывает, а с другой стороны вы могли бы не обращать внимания на всех остальных если бы у вас _получалось_, а если у вас не получается -- то лучше слушать тех, у кого получается и кто хочет помочь, а не пытаться навязать "у меня не получается, но делайте так как я сказал". Увы.

Comment: Хорошо, что вы решили защитить его. Я считаю помощью предложения решений, а не повторение того, что этот тег так не может. Я это уже понял. Вопрос сформулирован достаточно грамотно, чтобы понять его суть. Мне не нужно объяснять, что "тут так не получится", если тут не получится, то напишите где получится. Я задаю конкретный вопрос, а рассуждения и мнения на эту тему меня не интересуют

Comment: Меня интересует как можно реализовать нужную задачу, скрыть ссылку на видео, которая хронится во втором файле и подключается к данной странице. Мне кажется, что это предложение вполне доходчиво передаёт мой вопрос.